# Compiling Objective C with Clang

Tags: software-compilation, objective-c, clang

I have installed `clang` on my Raspberry Pi. How can I compile a `.m` file (Objective C) through the terminal?

Let's say I called it `bob.m` and I want the output file to be called `bob` and I'm already in the correct directory, what is the exact command?

Comment: If I use clang bob.m -o bob:     clang helloWorldObjC.m -o helloWorldObjC
helloWorldObjC.m:1:12: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file
      not found
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
           ^
1 error generated.

Answer (score 5):

To compile Object-C:

```
clang <the file name, i.e. bob.m> -o <the target name, i.e. bob>
```

so

```
clang bob.m -o bob
```

Foundation is part of GNUStep which will have to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep
```

You will then need to tell clang about it.

```
clang `gnustep-config --objc-flags` bob.m -o bob  `gnustep-config --base-libs`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instal the objective c run time libraries as well as OpenStep/gnuStep if you want to import foundation.h. Objective-c does not come bundled with clang.

Apparently you can get gnustep with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep
```

Once that is installed, you should be able to compile against foundation.h